# World / Global Navigable Waterway Data?

Tags: data

We're looking for an equivalent of "The National Waterway Network" dataset but for the entire world.  Essentially vector data of all non-ocean waterways including major rivers etc, that can be used for ships.  So this would exclude waterways like streams and drainages shown in typical hydro data.  Anyone aware of a source for this data either as a whole or a compilation of the sources for each specific country?

Ideally the worldwide data would have some sort of uniformity between countries.

Comment: Most likely per country and not always free like https://www.npms.phmsa.dot.gov/CNWData.aspx

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap.org holds river, and if you want to go into the sea, there is openseamap.org - Would that fit your purpose?

Or you could check out http://www.diva-gis.org/Data if you have the time to download by country, and join it together yourself.